# android:pass captured image from gridview to another Actvity

Tags: android, image, gridview

Good Day

I'm trying to pass captured image in gridview to another activity so I can display it in full-screen size..the problem is when I click on one item in the gridview the app is crush..**any help will be appreciated**

here is the code
**camera Fragment**

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {
Images images;
  byte[] image1;
    DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;
    private ImageListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Images> myLists;// image list
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
            databaseAdapter =new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
            databaseAdapter.open();
            myLists = new ArrayList<Images>();
            myLists =databaseAdapter.getImagesList();
            adapter = new ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.img_list_view, myLists);
            myGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            myGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   Images selectedItem = (Images ) myLists.get(position);
                   image1=selectedItem.getImageBlob();

                   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DisplayImage.class);
                   intent.putExtra("image1",image1);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   Log.w(TAG, "image Blob" + image1 );
               }
          });
            myGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            Button myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.camerabutton);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
```

**Display image Activity**

```
public class DisplayImage extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_invoice_image);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        databaseAdapter =new DatabaseAdapter(this);
        databaseAdapter.open();


        Intent i = getIntent();
        ImageView imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayFull);

        String image1 = i.getStringExtra("image1");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra(image1)));
```

here is the logcat

```
Key image1 expected String but value was a [B.  The default value <null> was returned.
06-08 07:44:25.251 10752-10752/com.example.labon.invoicemanger W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
                                                                         java.lang.ClassCastException: byte[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:923)
                                                                             at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5349)
                                                                             at com.example.labon.invoicemanger.DisplayImage.onCreate(DisplayImage.java:36)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-08 07:44:25.251 10752-10752/com.example.labon.invoicemanger E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
06-08 07:44:25.395 10752-10777/com.example.labon.invoicemanger W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: @Egor chcek the update

Comment: Looks like you're sending the image as a byte[] and trying to get it from the Intent as a String - so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ok..I trying to display that image in another activity @Egor